# Format date and Subtract days using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I would like a variable to hold yesterday's date in the format `DD-MM-YYYY` using Moment.js. So if today is `15-04-2015`, I would like to subtract a day and have `14-4-2015`.

I've tried a few combinations like this:

```
startdate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
startdate.subtract(1, 'd');
```

and this:

```
startdate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY').subtract(1, 'd');
```

and also this:

```
startdate = moment();
startdate.subtract(1, 'd');
startdate.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

But I'm not getting it...

Comment: Have you tried subtracting before formatting? Formatting it just gives you a string...

Comment: moment().subtract(10, "days") instead of just "d" maybe?

Comment: "Hold" yesterday's date as a **date**, and turn it into a formatted string when you need to display it.

Comment: @NickDugger i made a mistake in that question the last attempt should say startdate = moment(); in the first line. Ive edited it now thanks

Comment: `format()` is the function that makes it a string. You should do that last.

Comment: Your third example works for me but I am on `v2.7.0`.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

You have multiple oddities happening. The first has been edited in your post, but it had to do with the order that the methods were being called.

`.format` returns a string. String does not have a `subtract` method.

The second issue is that you are subtracting the day, but not actually saving that as a variable.

Your code, then, should look like:

```
var startdate = moment();
startdate = startdate.subtract(1, "days");
startdate = startdate.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

However, you can chain this together; this would look like:

```
var startdate = moment().subtract(1, "days").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

The difference is that we're setting startdate to the changes that you're doing on startdate, because moment is destructive.

Comment: moment.js `subtract` is, in fact, destructive. "Mutates the original moment by subtracting time". See here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

Answer (score 24):

```
var date = new Date();

var targetDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').toDate(); // date object
```

Now, you can format how you wanna see this date or you can compare this date with another etc.

`toDate()` function is the point.

Answer (score 16):

```
startdate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
var duration = moment.duration({'days' : 1});
moment().subtract(duration).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

This will give you `14-04-2015` - *today is 15-04-2015*

Alternatively if your momentjs version is less than 2.8.0, you can use:

```
startdate = moment().subtract('days', 1).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Instead of this:

```
startdate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 6):

In angularjs `moment="^1.3.0"`

```
moment('15-01-1979', 'DD-MM-YYYY').subtract(1,'days').format(); // 14-01-1979
```

or

```
moment('15-01-1979', 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(1,'days').format(); // 16-01-1979
```

Answer (score 4):

```
startdate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have got it in that last attempt, you just need to grab the string.. in Chrome's console..

```
startdate = moment();
startdate.subtract(1, 'd');
startdate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
"14-04-2015"

startdate = moment();
startdate.subtract(1, 'd');
myString = startdate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
"14-04-2015"
myString
"14-04-2015"
```