# How to subtract one year from a Date type in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, datetimepicker

I want to subtract one year from a `Date` in my Angular component. This is my  template:

```html
<input type="date" [value]="date" (change)="date=$event.target.value" class="form-control"
/>
```

And the associated class:

```
export class appResultadosUtenteComponent {
    date: string;

    constructor() {
        this.date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You could use [`Date#setFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) to set the year to one less than [`Date#getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear):

```js
const now = new Date();
now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() - 1);

document.write(now.toISOString().slice(0,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the moment library to do this:

- [Format date and Subtract days using Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651815/format-date-and-subtract-days-using-moment-js)

Here is the way to configure it:

```
<script>
  System.configure({
    map: {
      (...)
      'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment'
    },
    (...)
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Could use Moment.js

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

todayDate: Date = new Date();
lastDate = moment(this.todayDate).substract(1, 'year').format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
```