# Calculate departure day based on arrival date and duration of program

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Learning examples in comments of *E&P Plugin for WordPress*

I found a few bugs myself, but still can't make the code work.

Case: Choose **Arrival date** (date-picker) and **program duration** from select field (5|7|14|30|60) in days. Generate **Departure date**

This code from plugin owner don't word at all

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('[data-title="Departure"]').on('change',checkDates);
  jQuery('[data-title="Program"]').on('change',checkDates);
});

function checkDates(){
  var nbDays = jQuery('[data-title="Program"] option:selected').attr('data-price');
    var startDate = moment(jQuery('[data-title="Arrival"]').datetimepicker('getDate'));
    var endDate = startDate.subtract(nbDays,'days');
    jQuery('[data-title="Departure"]').datetimepicker('setDate',endDate.toDate());

}
```

From first view I find that he use `subtract` instead of `add`

I using https://momentjs.com/docs/ and [Format date and Subtract days using Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651815/format-date-and-subtract-days-using-moment-js)

```
var startdate = moment();
startdate = startdate.subtract(1, "days");
```

is equal

```
var startdate = moment().subtract(1, "days");
```

So this is mine version:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('[data-title="Arrival"]').on('change',checkDates);
jQuery('[data-title="Program"]').on('change',checkDates);
});

function checkDates(){
  var nbDays = jQuery('[data-title="Program"] option:selected').attr('data-price');
    var startDate = moment(jQuery('[data-title="Arrival"]').datetimepicker('getDate'));
    var endDate = moment().add(nbDays,'days');
    jQuery('[data-title="Departure"]').datetimepicker('setDate',endDate.toDate());
}
```

Still not recalculate departure date `on.click` and count days not properly

Comment: Is `attr('data-price')` correct? Just from the naming of the attribute it seems to have nothing to do with a date. To check if every value is what you expect it to be you could `console.log` the variables and check them in your browser console.

Comment: This is a name of filed, there stored number of days like 7|14|30 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get a wrong end-date because you are doing `moment().add(...)` which gets the current date at the script execution (equelevant of `Date.now()`).

Try to use the startDate variable and using moment prototype add on that instead:

`var endDate = startDate.add(nbDays,'days');`

This will make moment add additional days to the startDate instead of the current date.

End result:

```
function checkDates(){
    var nbDays = jQuery('[data-title="Program"] option:selected').attr('data-price');
    var startDate = moment(jQuery('[data-title="Arrival"]').datetimepicker('getDate'));
    var endDate = startDate.add(nbDays,'days');
    jQuery('[data-title="Departure"]').datetimepicker('setDate',endDate.toDate());
}
```

Comment: you right, now calculate dates correctly, but still don't recalculate on.change. Only if I change both parameters step-by -step few times