# Get total sums for last 3, 7, 30 and 90 days with moment

Tags: javascript

I have an array of orders with created_at and total fields, where created_at is the date the order was created and total is what the user paid.

Now I want to get the sum of the totals for four different date intervals, last 3 days, 7 days, 30 days and 90 days, how can I use moment to check if an order is between these intervals and get the total sum for each interval.

```
const getIntervalsSum = (orders) =>
    {
       var threeDaysSum = 0;
       var sevenDaysSum = 0;
       var thirtyDaysSum = 0;
       var ninetyDaysSum = 0;
       
       for(var i=0; i<orders.length;i++)
       {
           //check interval with moment() here and add to respective sums
       }

    };
```

Comment: You can use the [subtract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651815/format-date-and-subtract-days-using-moment-js) featue to get the date x days back then check if today is after with the [isAfter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates)

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample input and the result you'd want to get for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one generic function best suits this situation. Haven't used moment before but based on the docs, this looks like it will work.

```
const totalOrders = (orders, daysAgo) => {
    let sum = 0;
    const then = moment().subtract(daysAgo, 'days');

    orders.forEach((order) => {
        if (moment(order.created_at).isAfter(then)) {
            sum += order.total;
        }
    });

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may work

```
const getIntervalsSum = (orders) =>
    {
       var threeDaysSum = 0;
       var sevenDaysSum = 0;
       var thirtyDaysSum = 0;
       var ninetyDaysSum = 0;
       let  today= moment()
       for(var i=0; i<orders.length;i++)
       {
        let order_create_date = moment(orders[i].create_date);
        let dif= order_create_date.diff(today, 'days') 
        // differnce between today and ordered date
        if(dif<=3) threeDaysSum += orders[i].total_amount;
        if(dif<=7) sevenDaysSum += orders[i].total_amount;
        if(dif<=30) thirtyDaysSum += orders[i].total_amount;
        if(dif<=90) ninthDaysSum += orders[i].total_amount;
       }

    };
```